Why time based neuron still needed when the time-series data can be converted to time-freq domain (image) and use CNN for that?
LSTM, BI-LSTM, GRU, RNN are time-step based neuron. Why it still needed specifically for time-series data?
I mean, we can just transform the time-series data into spectrogram and use CNN for that.
For example, given time series data (vector) and its sample rate (scalar). We can preprocess data with Short-time Fourier Transform (STFT). Hence, our tensor will be transformed from 1D (vector) to 2D (matrix).
Basically, transforming 1D signal to 2D signal (image). Where 1D signal has 2 axis (x-axis is time and y-axis is amplitude). While 2D signal has 3 axis (x is time, y is frequency, and the amount of pixel intensity is amplitude).
So, its dimension for training will be transformed from (batch_size, amplitude) to (batch_size, width, height, 1).
With this, we don't need time dependencies anymore with just using CNN, Therefore, true parallel processing can be achieved with AI accelerator. As far as I know AI accelerators have some problem for parallel processing for time based neuron such as LSTM.
